# Flask SQLite3 DB Connection: NameError: name 'connect_db' is not defined

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Following along on the Real Python Discover Flask series and trying to connect to my Sqlite3 database through iPython shell. Not using SQL Alchemy or anything else.

Error message is:

```
In [1]: from app import *

In [2]: c = connect_db()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 c = connect_db()

NameError: name 'connect_db' is not defined
```

Most logic is in my **init**.py file:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash
from functools import wraps
import sqlite3
from app install app

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.SECRET_KEY = "my precious"
    app.database = "sample.db"

    # login required decorator
    def login_required(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if 'logged_in' in session:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                flash('You need to login first.')
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
        return wrap

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # a simple page that says hello
    @app.route('/hello')
    @login_required
    def hello():
        return render_template('home.html')

    @app.route('/')
    @login_required
    def home():
        return render_template('index-START.html')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()

    # Route for handling the login page logic
    @app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
        error = None
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
                error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
            else:
                session['logged_in'] = True
                flash('You were just logged in!')
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
        return render_template('login.html', error=error)

    @app.route('/logout')
    @login_required
    def logout():
        session.pop('logged_in', None)
        flash('You were just logged out !')
        return redirect(url_for('hello'))

    def connect_db():
        return sqlite3.connect(app.database)

    return app

# # start the server with the 'run()' method
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my sql.py file:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('sample.db') as connection:
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE posts(title TEXT, description TEXT)""")
    c.execute('INSERT INTO posts VALUES("Good", "I\'m good.")')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO posts VALUES("Well", "I\'m well.")')
```

So far, I have:

- Checked for typos
- Checked all similar questions on SO
- Closed out and restarted everything: new instance of the app, new session in shell, fresh relaunch of server
- Checked my imports (I suspect something is missing here, tried import app from app with no luck)
- Dropped the DB and recreated it (DB exists and works fine but for some reason is not connecting).
- moved connect_db() around in **init**.py, with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Connect_db is defined within another function. As long as this function is not ran, the connect_db function also won't be defined.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But didn't the function run when I created an instance of the app? 

export FLASK_APP=[app name] 
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run

I did this again after fixing everything to make sure but just asking so I understand.

Comment: I think that the function is ran inside some flask file and that the function thus is not in the global scope.

Comment: I tried moving the function out of def create_app(test_config=None) but it does not work. Also, if    from app import *     works, I think this should mean an instance of the app was created, right? 

If this is true, then the function      def create_app(test_config=None)     is being run and     def connect_db()   is being run too.